# Push notification in Windows phone 7.1 throwing error PushSharp.WindowsPhone.WindowsPhoneNotificationSendFailureException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, windows-7, push-notification, pushsharp

I am trying to send a push notification in my windows phone 7.1 which is throwing error:

```
PushSharp.WindowsPhone.WindowsPhoneNotificationSendFailureException
```

Following is the middle-ware code written in server side:

```
        var push = new PushBroker();
        push.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
        push.OnChannelException += ChannelException;
        push.OnServiceException += ServiceException;
        push.OnNotificationFailed += NotificationFailed;
        push.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += DeviceSubscriptionExpired;
        push.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += DeviceSubscriptionChanged;
        push.OnChannelCreated += ChannelCreated;
        push.OnChannelDestroyed += ChannelDestroyed;

         // WINDOWS PHONE NOTIFICATIONS
        push.RegisterWindowsPhoneService();

        push.QueueNotification(new WindowsPhoneToastNotification()
            .ForEndpointUri(new Uri(url))
            .ForOSVersion(WindowsPhoneDeviceOSVersion.Seven)
            .WithBatchingInterval(BatchingInterval.Immediate)
            // .WithNavigatePath("/MainPage.xaml")
            .WithText1("Notification")
            .WithText2("This is a push notification"));
        push.StopAllServices(waitForQueuesToFinish: true);
```

The Push sharp handler methods are:

```
    //this even raised when a notification is successfully sent
    static void NotificationSent(object sender, INotification notification)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Sent: " + sender + " -> " + notification);
    }

    //this is raised when a notification is failed due to some reason
    static void NotificationFailed(object sender, INotification notification, Exception notificationFailureException)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Failure: " + sender + " -> " + notificationFailureException.Message + " -> " + notification);
    }
```

From Front End using VS 2010 for windows phone framework I am sending the URL something like this which is auto generated:

```
Notification channel URI:http://db3.notify.live.net/throttledthirdparty/01.00/AQE9Hz23hR07RYiaH7O3SeEkAgAAAAADAQAAAAQUZm52OjIzOEQ2NDJDRkI5MEVHHSNLL8wMQ
```

But unfortunately, I am receiving the following exception :

```
Failure: PushSharp.WindowsPhone.WindowsPhonePushService -> Exception of type 'PushSharp.WindowsPhone.WindowsPhoneNotificationSendFailureException' was thrown. -> <wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">
```

Help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Same Code worked when I tried with the **Device**

not **Emulator**. May be that error occurred because of dummy *credentials*.